404 not found on Magento2 and nginx, Ubuntu
I've been trying to set up my magento2 on nginx server but when i tried to access the page via url, it said 404 page not found.
here is the 404 not found
I followed this instruction on magento website:
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/web-server/nginx#install-and-configure-mysql-1
I did almost everything like this instruction except the last step to Configure SELinux and Firewalld as I read that enabling SeLinux is very risky.
An answer and solution to fix this problem

If you're encountering a 404 Not Found error on Magento 2 with Nginx on Ubuntu, the issue is typically related to Nginx configuration, file permissions, or Magento settings.

It's way better to install magento in a custom url. You can do this by editing hosts file and adding custom domain to nginx configuration. Using folder might be the issue here.

The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

To install Magento2 with nginx server in Ubuntu, follow these steps.
Step-1: Create nginx host file in below path
Path: /etc/nginx/sites-available/ 
Filename: /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento.conf 
Add these contents, modify FPM server, Magento Base URL and Magento installation paths.
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

server {

  listen 80;
  server_name magento_url.local;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento2;
  include /var/www/html/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
  client_max_body_size 100M;
}

Step-2: Create symlink
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/magento.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Step-3: Verify if nginx configuration is correct. On running this command, there should not be any errors.
nginx -t

Step-4: Add Magento Base URL in system host file
nano /etc/hosts

Append these contents
127.0.0.1 custom_url.local

Step-5: - Restart nginx and FPM servers
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
sudo /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm restart

These are the required steps to configure Magento2 to run with Nginx server
